# CSS Layout not aligning correctly

Tags: css, layout

I am trying to achieve the layout shown in the picture with CSS. I am currently using `float:left;` for both text sections with a `width: 100%;` but they keep moving below the fixed image on the left.

[image]

```
<div style="float:left;">
 <div style="width: 100px; height: 200px;">
   Some Image
 </div>
 <div style="float:left;">
  <div style="float:left; width: 100%;">Some text</div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 100%;">Some text</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give a width to your parent section ```<div style="float:left;">```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn’t need that much floating and/or explicit widths.

`overflow:hidden` can be used to make the element next to the floated image keep that reduced width, instead of being laid out under the whole image (which is the effect float normally has - the div itself would still go over the whole width, and only its *content* flows around the image.)

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  outline: 1px dashed;
}

.container img {
  float: left;
}

.container div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x200">
  <div>
    <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text </p>
    <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is more style issue and can be done by making second div to align/float right. Further you can use width on outer div too.

```
 <div style="float:left; width: 40%">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 200px;">
      Some Image
    </div>
 <div>
 <div style="float:right; width: 60%">
    <div style="float:left; width: 100%;">Some text</div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 100%;">Some text</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div style="float:left; width: 40%">
        <div style="width: 100px;">
          Some Image
        </div>
     <div>
     <div style="float:right; width: 60%">
        <div style="float:left;">Some text</div>
        <div style="float:left; width: 100%;">Some text</div>
     </div>

Problem is Height 200px is remove than check please
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{padding:20px;}
body div{margin:5px;}
.main{display:block; border:2px #333 solid;  width:100%;  overflow:hidden;}
.vert{ padding:1%; border:2px #333 solid; width:20%;
  height:200px; float:left; }
.vert img{width:100%}
.hor{position:relative; left:0px; righ:0px; width:66%; float:left; }
.hor div{border:2px #333 solid; width:99%;  margin-bottom:5px; padding:5%;}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="vert"><img src="https://cdn4.buysellads.net/uu/1/3386/1525189887-61450.png"></div>
  <div class="hor">
  <div>Some Text some text some text</div>
  <div>Some Text some text some text</div>
    <div>Some Text some text some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```